# partials of a PDF with no closed form solution

Tags: probability

I need to estimate partial derivatives for all N parameters denoted $\theta_{N}$ of a probability density function(PDF) $\mathcal{f}$.

This PDF $\mathcal{f}$ has no closed form solution and is instead expressed in terms of a characteristic function $\phi$ and an FFT $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$.

$\mathcal{f}(x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\phi(x)]$

Is it possible to estimate the partial derivative with respect to $\theta_{N}$, $\frac {\partial \mathcal{f}} {\theta_{N}}$  for all N parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta_{N}}=\mathcal F^{-1}\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial\theta_{N}}\right)
$$